# ggplot2 prevent months from repeating on y axis

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I plotting a time series where I take the average day an event occurs over the years. I'm trying to plot this with the months on the Y axis, the years on the x-axis.  but the months repeat for each year. For example, I have two events that occur in January on 2006, and 2007. I don't need two separate January's on the y-axis, just one. Attached is the image of what I'm getting, you can see the months repeat on the y-axis. I'm not sure how to fix this. Below is the table of my data (test1), followed by my code to plot, only three lines:

```
 Zone Year       Mean      PosSD      NegSD
1 zone4 2006 2006-07-19 2007-01-13 2006-01-23
2 zone4 2007 2007-05-29 2007-11-04 2006-12-22
3 zone4 2008 2008-01-12 2008-01-15 2008-01-09


  FI_plot<- ggplot(test1, aes(x=Year, y = Mean))+
    geom_point()+ 
    scale_y_date(date_labels = "%b, %d", date_breaks = "1 month")
```

[image: Image of output plot]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data. You can do it with `dput()` function.

Comment: I added the table of my data, it's pretty small. Table name is test1. I'm trying to plot the mean column, disregard the last two columns

Comment: You're mapping a date to the y aesthetic, and dates don't reset when the year changes. You'd need to create a month variable and relabel, e.g. `test1$mean_month <- as.integer(format(test1$Mean, '%m')); 

ggplot(test1, aes(Year, mean_month))+
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the “Mean”column is a date which year changes for each row.
If you want to plot only the “day”, the easiest solution is to assign all
rows to the same year (does not matter which year). Something like this would work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Zone = c("zone4", "zone4", "zone4"),
        Year = c(2006, 2007, 2008),
        Mean = as.Date(c("2006-07-19", "2007-05-29", "2008-01-12")),
       PosSD = as.Date(c("2007-01-13", "2007-11-04", "2008-01-15")),
       NegSD = as.Date(c("2006-01-23", "2006-12-22", "2008-01-09")))

# replace current year with 1900 
dd$Mean  <- as.Date(gsub("[0-9]{4}-", "1900-", dd$Mean))
dd$PosSD <- as.Date(gsub("[0-9]{4}-", "1900-", dd$PosSD))
dd$NegSD <- as.Date(gsub("[0-9]{4}-", "1900-", dd$NegSD))
dd
#>    Zone Year       Mean      PosSD      NegSD
#> 1 zone4 2006 1900-07-19 1900-01-13 1900-01-23
#> 2 zone4 2007 1900-05-29 1900-11-04 1900-12-22
#> 3 zone4 2008 1900-01-12 1900-01-15 1900-01-09

# plot
FI_plot<- ggplot(dd, aes(x=Year, y = Mean))+
          geom_point() + 
          scale_y_date(date_labels = "%b, %d", date_breaks = "1 month")

FI_plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>